# Asynch task inside timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, sleep

I want to replace Thread.sleep() in my window service application. but i am not getting how to use it in my code. In my service i have to iterate a list of machines in foreach loop after every 10 minutes and  in that loop i have started new thread after some time delay e.g. 2 seconds delay. so i am using thread.sleep() after every thread creation. What should i do to replace Thread.sleep() i have to use asynch task in timer but i am not getting how to convert it in asynch task.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    this.timer1.Interval = 10000;
    this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach( var list in machinelist)
    {
        createComAndMessagePumpThread2 = new Thread(() =>
               {
                   // connection with machines code using list
                   Application.Run();
               });
        createComAndMessagePumpThread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        createComAndMessagePumpThread2.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is really badly formatted.

Comment: Try using Task.Delay https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to convert `Thread.Sleep()` to the equivalent async method, this will do the work:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async ()=> { while(true) await LunchTasks(); });
}

private Task LunchTasks()
{
    var tasks = machinelist.Select(machinelist=> 
    foreach( var machinelist in machinelist)
    {
        createComAndMessagePumpThread2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
           // connection with machines code using list
           Application.Run();
        });
        createComAndMessagePumpThread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        createComAndMessagePumpThread2.Start();
        return Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

But you will barely benefit from it. Periodically spinning a new thread for each "application" is a lot more costly than the one thread you block on `Thread.Sleep()`. If you want to use the full power of asynchronous programming, you will have to figure out how to decouple the application from the physical thread. You need to get used to the notion of `Task` rather than `Thread` for that matter. Hopefully your program is able to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Is the delay really needed, since the OS will presumably manage resources for you as the applications start up? Why not just do something like this?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{    
    Parallel.ForEach(
        machinelist, (list) => 
        {
            var Application = //however you do this...
            Application.Run();
        }
    );
}
```

...and use a [different TaskScheduler](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d4c66fd-e716-41ec-8b4d-2620400a0150/parallelforeach-unable-to-control-apartmentstate?forum=parallelextensions) if needed.

Comment: This won't add the 2 second delay between each loop iteration.

Comment: @Mangist - You're right. I deleted the confusing comment. What I meant to get at is that it's worth asking the question of if the delay is really needed.